Safe to remove wall separation between two closets?
I have two double sliding door closets in my master bedroom that are side by side. Between the two closets is a drywall partition, the same depth as the closets, separating the two.
I'm looking to install/DIY hack an IKEA PAX wardrobe system to improve the organization of the closet and get somewhat of a "built in" look. Is it safe enough to remove the small drywall partition between the two closets? I can't imagine it being structural or have any services running within it. Aside from patching the drywall and flooring after removing the wall, is there anything else I should consider?



In a residential situation with no floors above this one, you're probably safe. The location of the wall and its short length indicate a simple partition.
Open the drywall on one side and have a look. If you find anything other than common studs and a wall plate, reevaluate the situation.
See also Are there ways to determine if a wall is load bearing?

The ceiling actually isn't sloped, it must be the angle of the photo.  But you are correct, there's no floors above this one (unfinished attic space).  On the other side of the closets is another closet for another bedroom.  I'll open a section of the drywall as you suggested and see what's in there.  Thanks!

@Traveler The ceiling inside the closet really isn't sloped at all!?!  Some optical illusion!!!

@JeopardyTempest well, the floor is angled up too!

Wow. You must have your phone in superwide mode. That's wild. Anyway, my answer wouldn't change unless the closet is right in the middle of your home and there's a chance it supports a roof girder.

The questing is what direction are the joists above the wall running? If they are parallel with the wall then it will be safe as it is non-supporting. If the joists are perpendicular then the wall is providing some support. You would need an engineer or experience contractor on-site to evaluate in that instance.
If it is perpendicular then it SHOULD be possible to remove MOST of the wall. But get professional advice. Keep the 2 doors with the stud between them. Put another stud at the back wall (2 if you want to be extra safe but if it is will screwed into the back wall it should be ok) then run a header beam (2 2x4's or 2x6's) across the top between the 2 walls. This will provide the support without the need for the wall.
You may need to reinforce the front stud between the 2 doors. Make absolutely certain that the header is resting on TOP of the supporting studs - toenailing it will not support any weight and it will eventually collapse.

Your second sentence is incorrect more often than it's correct in modern homes. Even in older ones with hand-framed ceilings there's no reason to think the joists over that wall would actually rest on it, especially since there are presumably many other adjacent ones that don't.

Thanks for the revision. This is why he needs to check for parallel or perpendicular. If perpendicular, like I said get an engineer or contractor to confirm it's ok but if parallel there will be no problems.
I edited my answer to clarify. Thanks for the heads up.
